# characters in field

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript, primeng

I've been doing a lot of research on this and still can't find a good solution. Basically, I have this field in my form that should **ONLY** allow numbers. However, I'm able to enter **mac special characters** inside that field by doing:

Hold down **option** + **shift** and then pressing any button from keyboard (example: h j k l u i , etc).

**Please see attached picture.**

Can anyone help me on NOT allowing such characters inside the ID field? Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's my code:

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y9fffq?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

```
ID: <input formControlName="userid" type="text" pKeyFilter="num" placeholder="Numbers" pInputText>
```

Comment: didn't `type="number" ` worked?

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem to work in firefox? and I may need to test it on IE as well

Comment: type = number should do it. And browsers that don't support it should default back to text. And remember that it's just an aid for the user. In the end you have to validate input on the server anyway, because you never know how they send their data. Could be a really old browser or even a custom script or just cUrl..

Comment: If you do not want to allow non-ASCII symbols, use `^[ -~]*$` to validate or `[^ -~]+` to remove invalid chars.

Comment: In normal JavaScript it would be easy, but you are using Angular 7, so if the default "number" validator doesn't do what you want, it looks like you need to make a [custom validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators).

Comment: @OldPro how would your solution be in normal JavaScript?

Comment: See [here (code)](https://people.apache.org/~jim/NewArchitect/docs/new1013637813/lst-1.htm) and [here (explanation)](https://people.apache.org/~jim/NewArchitect/webtech/1998/01/junk/index.html) for one way to do it in plain JavaScript.

Comment: I can also paste some word characters inside the input. I suggest you to handle the `paste` event too

Comment: `'ÍÓÍ¨Åˆ'.replace( /[^\d]+/gi, '' )`.
your provided demo link just simply didn't run for me, but I believe search within input string by a regular expression like `/[^\d]+/gi' and replace all characters found with an empty string `''` would do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many approaches to this problem. All of the provided solutions should work. My recommendation is Approach 2.

**Approach 1**

You can try to remove non number characters on the input event like this

```
<input 
    formControlName="userid"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Numbers"
    oninput="javascript: this.value = this.value.replace(new RegExp('[^0-9]', 'gm'), '')"
    pInputText
/>
```

[Modified Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6cnyzt)

I tested this in Firefox and Chrome on MacOS and it seems to work fine.

**Approach 2**

To do this from your angular module:

Use a simple text input

```
<input
    formControlName="userid"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Number"
    pInputText
/>
```

Listen to changes and patch the value accordingly. Don't forget to register your observers on init.

```
registerChangeObservers() {
    this.registrationFormGroup.get("userid").valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      this.registrationFormGroup.patchValue({
        'userid': val.replace(new RegExp('[^0-9]', 'gm'), '')
      }, { emitEvent: false });
    });
  }

ngOnInit() {
    this.registerChangeObservers();
  }
```

Especially note the `{ emitEvent: false }` part. You need to set this to avoid recursion. This approach can fail if your model becomes invalid and therefore it's value changes to nil. For example this can happen if you set your input type to number, but a user manages to input a non number character. To avoid this make sure the input validation doesn't fail on special characters, e.g. by setting the input type to text.

[Demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ueuxue)

**Approach 3**

To avoid the display of modifying characters you can also listen to input events (i.e. key presses) instead of actual value changes. This is equivalent to approach 1.
To do so use this input

```
<input
    formControlName="userid"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Number" 
    pInputText
    (input)="onPress($event)"
/>
```

and add this function to your controller

```
onPress($event) {
    this.registrationFormGroup.patchValue({
        'userid': $event.target.value.replace(new RegExp('[^0-9]', 'gm'), '')
      }, { emitEvent: false });
  }
```

[Demo 3](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urvqpw)

Note: I would generally avoid this approach because in my experience the suppression of modifying characters can have unintended side effects with some uncommon input methods, especially on mobile. The approach above (Approach 2) also works and is safer in my opinion. Although modifying characters are displayed, they will disappear on the next user action and will never be present in your model data.

Comment: How would you use your regex from angular instead fo doing it from the view?

Comment: @HenryDev you can do the same thing from your angular module. But note that this listens to changes of the *model*. So if your model becomes invalid for some reason, e.g. because you set the type to number and someone entered a special character, this solution stops working. So make sure your model allows any input. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: @heilerich I'm using your provided demo and it doesn't seem to work. Let's say you hold down the Option button then press a letter like e, u , o you will see that it still allows special characters.

Comment: @progx I assume that you are talking about characters like " and `? These are actually placeholders that modify the next input. They are not actually in the field yet, they're just displayed for your convenience until you press the next key to enter the definite modified character like ö (" and o). You can see that they have no influence on your model by looking at the JSON on the bottom of the form field. The second you're pressing the next key, focus an other input field or submit the form the should vanish from the input.

Comment: @heilerich your solution doesn't work when holding down Option button and pressing some of these letters: e, u , o

Comment: @HenryDev please see my previous comment regarding this issue

Comment: @heilerich yup I saw the comment. The thing is: when I use your regex on the view it works at 100%, but when I use it from the component it doesn't work at 100%. I'm looking for a solution from the component and not from the view.

Comment: @HenryDev what I tried to explain in my previous comment is, that the solution actually works. These special characters *look* like they’re there, but actually they are *not*. You wont find them anywhere in your model or post data. They will actually disappear as soon as the user takes his next action

Comment: As per your request I added a solution that suppresses modifying characters above, but I advise against it.

Comment: Thanks for your effort bro, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You have already tried with:

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]{10}" />
```

the following validates a 10-digit number, and I also think you should do a validation with JavaScript:

```
<input type="text" id="text" onblur="validaNumericos();" />
```

Function Javascript:

```js
function validaNumericos(){
 var inputtxt = document.getElementById('text'); 
 var valor = inputtxt.value;
 for(i=0;i<valor.length;i++){
     var code=valor.charCodeAt(i);
         if(code<=48 || code>=57){          
           inputtxt.value=""; 
           return;
         }    
   }
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" onblur="validaNumericos();" />
```

Comment: This solution is not working at 100%. It still allows the user to enter at least one of those mac characters

Answer (score 0):

Use `input` [type=number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number).

```
ID: <input formControlName="userid" type="number" pKeyFilter="num" placeholder="Numbers" pInputText>
```

If you don't like the dial controls on the right side, you can disable them with this in your css:

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```

Here is a [fork of your demo with all the changes](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wumrcw?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: Your solution doesn't work when holding down option button and then pressing some letters such as: u, i , e, etc

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are looking for a regex answer (based on your tag), you can test on the length of the pre-regex value vs. the length of the post regex value.
if there are extra characters, the lengths will not match.

```
[0-9]+
```

Comment: How would you implement that in the angular component?

Comment: once you get the value in the field, via submit button probably, get the length.  Then, apply the regex to the value.  It will pull out only the matching characters (note: in the non-US/non-Western world there are more than 10 digits), if it pulled out any of the characters then the length would be less.

Comment: I need to implement it on keypress event, so far I still can't get it to work

Comment: can you get it to compare the lengths?